# Eclipse displaying images in a java applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I want to display a simple image of a ball in my applet (using getCodeBase()), but when I run my applet, either nothing is displayed, or I get a syntax error from eclipse on my String argument in the getImage method.
My error is "Syntax error: invalid escape sequences. Only \b \n \f \" \' allowed."

My image is stored in C:\Java\eclipse\Images(Java)\ball.gif

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Image1 extends Applet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Image pic;
    public void init(){
        pic = getImage(getCodeBase(), "\Images(Java)\ball.gif");
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(pic,0,0,this);
        g.drawImage(pic, 100,100,125,100,this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read more about escape characters in java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: 1) What is the HTML used to launch the applet?  2) Note that all slashes in the image path should be an URL so use forward slash `/`, as opposed to back-slash - a (Windows only) file path. 3) Remove the leading bcak-slash from the string, since that means 'root of the site'.  In this case, it equates to a path of `C:\Images(Java)\ball.gif`.

Comment: I didn't use HTML because I wrote it in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some tips...

- A) You cannot get local image with `getCodeBase()` method because it
  returns http://... applet location path. In your IDE case, http is not available...
- B) To get host image with `getCodeBase()` you have to deploy your
  applet on a real host instead of testing it with `AppletViewer`
- C) If you just need an image for testing your applet in IDE you can simply get it
  by using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). As I can remember `AppletViewer` is OK with `io.*;` lib

Good luck

Comment: OK...you've told me how **not** to do it but how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You say you have the applet in Eclipse so the applet is not deployed. If it is not deployed yet you cannot use getCodeBase() because it returns applet HOST root only; If you need just to test your applet before deploy, read step C; If you want to get image in your applet hosted mode then read step B; And to see the whole picture show the getImage(...,...) method code...